# Angular Unit Tests using Karma, error with test branch or serviceSpy ()

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I am currently testing an angular application in Angular 7, but I can't figure out how to test this branch of the submit function, I have approximately more 20 tests in this component, and some of them even use the same service spy as the test that isn't working:

The branch:

```
submit(): void {

    if (this.systemTable) {
      // this.formArray = this.formBuilder.array([]);
      while (this.formArray.length) {
        this.formArray.removeAt(0);
        console.log('dfdfdf');
      } //this.formArray.removeAt(0);


    } //...
```

My test:

```
it('submit() should remove when systemTable is true', () => {
    app.ngOnInit();

    app.systemTable = true; //Entering the branch i wan't to test

    const f = app.formArray; 
    app.addRow(); //This function adds a row into the app.formRow, I checked it's values with a debugger and it's working
    const userServiceSpy = spyOn(app.formArray, 'removeAt');

    app.submit();
    expect(userServiceSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
```

Comment: Is you using the same spy multiple time push it to a higher scope. I mostly define them in the beforeEach. Like: `let spy: any;` and then `beforeEach(() => { spy = spyOn() })`. This is a comment not an answer cause you have no clear question, so can't give a clear answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the loop from while to for, in angular 8 this loop will no longer be needed.